# Unexpected text in the created layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout and not even touched the java code yet. So, no dynamic data added. I have finished my design in eclipse and its layout editor looks fine and in sync with my design. But as I run the application, I get a un expected text "1" at the bottom of the layouts. I have checked the Dump View **Hierarchy for UI automator tool** and found that I have a EditText covered with a RelativeLayout covered with a Framelayout which lies at the bottom of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NotificationActivity"
android:background="@color/app_bg_color"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_unselected"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="3dp"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgUnnotified"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/unnotified_duties"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgUnnotified" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/unnotified_duties"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_unselected">
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="3dp"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgWarning"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/unnotified_duties"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgWarning"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/warnings" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_unselected"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="3dp"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgBroadcast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/unnotified_duties"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBroadcast" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/broadcast_messages"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_unselected"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="2dp" 
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="3dp"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgAltPax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/warnings"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgAltPax" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="@string/alt_pax_Notifications"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**************EDIT************************

I have chaged the layout to a fragment and added the fragment dynamically. Now I get that value "1" before my entire layout.

*************EDIT**************************

Even more simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout displays "1" with the black background.

Comment: can you post your design what you want to do. you written your xml code very doubt full.

Comment: I have added the image. But it is not getting uploaded into the post

Comment: Its basically a tile kind of look with images and couple of textViews in it.

Comment: Naresh just draw in paint and post . with out knowing ,its not possible

Comment: isn't your main LinearLayout open? `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: @Rajeev I have pasted the entire layout correctly. The last close tag is not visible in this page. When I click edit, it is shown. And The images that I uploaded are not visible as well.

Comment: I don't even understand the problem. Is that "1" character which bothers you? I see in each `TextView` that character hardcoded, so no dynamic data so far, only the hardocded one.

Comment: Yes. I have hardcoded "1" in for places. I am not talking about that textView. Those are in 4 RelativeLayouts. I find a character "1" at the bottom of the screen. It is surronded by a Relativelayout which in turn by a frame layout.

Comment: Kindly see my edit as well. It may give a better idea.